# Getting services from the command class

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

How can I get a service from the command class? I have been trying to use `ContainerAwareCommand` as the parent of my command class, and then just using `$this->getContainer()->get('my_service')`, but when I run the command in cli, I get the following error:

Call to undefined method `Symfony\Component\Console\Application::getKernel()`

inside the `getContainer()` method of the `ContainerAwareCommand` class.

The file through which I run the command is:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';

    use AppBundle\Console\Command\ChangeEmailCommand;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
    use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
    $debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

    if ($debug) {
        Debug::enable();
    }

    $kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->add(new ChangeEmailCommand());
    $application->run();
```

Comment: You need to call setContainer on your email command.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `Application` of the FrameworkBundle instead of the Console component. This class extends the one in the Console component, but adds awareness of the Kernel and the Container. Your Application version doesn't have this awareness (as it's designed for standalone use, outside of the Symfony context), resulting in a "method getKernel() does not exists".

So change this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
```

To:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
```

---

Btw, normally you won't need to create this file yourself. You can just use `app/console` in the Standard Edition: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/console when you installed Symfony using the installer/`composer create-project`.